# Какой тип связи придаточных в предложении?

Tags: спп, синтаксис

Какой тип связи придаточных в предложении:

> Хотя двор и сад были в тени, но уже
> ранние лучи золотили большие тыквы,
> которые находились на крыше и которые
> еще не поспели.

Я думаю - параллельное и однородное, правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Хотя двор и сад были в тени), но [уже ранние лучи золотили большие тыквы], (которые находились на крыше) и (которые еще не поспели)* - да, параллельное и однородное подчинени.